# XQuery : how can I quickly compare 2 id from different XML files?

Tags: xml, xquery

So I have these 2 XML files :

datas.xml

```
<datas>
  <data id="1"><place>Mu</place></data>
  <data id="2"><place>Atlantis</place></data>
  ...
  <data id="28492"><place>Mu</place></data>
</datas>
```

ingrs.xml

```
<ingrs>
  <ingr id="1">...</ingr>
  <ingr id="2">...</ingr>
  ...
  <ingr id="83882">...</ingr>
</ingrs>
```

The first thing I do is to only keep the ids of wanted data. But then I want to do a for statement that quickly finds the ingr with the same id (unique) instead of scanning any of the 83882 ingrs of the file.

```
let $ids := //data[./place = 'Mu']/@id return
  for $i in //ingr
  where() (: what to do here ? Something like $i/@id = $ids :)
  return $i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first thing I do is to only keep the ids of wanted data. But then
>   I want to do a for statement that quickly finds the ingr with the same
>   `id` (unique) instead of scanning any of the 83882 ingrs of the file.

I don't believe a "quicker" way of doing this is possible in standard XQuery -- the below query still has a worst time complexity of O(N*M), where `N` and `M` are, respectively, the number of the `data` and `ingr` elements in the two XML documents.

In XSLT one can define a key (index) on any node that is a function of other nodes and this index can produce near to O(1) fast searches, when used.

**Use**:

```
let $doc1 :=
    <datas>
      <data id="1"><place>Mu</place></data>
      <data id="2"><place>Atlantis</place></data>
      ...
      <data id="28492"><place>Mu</place></data>
    </datas>

    , $doc2 :=
        <ingrs>
          <ingr id="1">...</ingr>
          <ingr id="2">...</ingr>
          ...
          <ingr id="83882">...</ingr>
        </ingrs>,
        $data := $doc1//data[place='Mu'],
        $ids := $data/@id
  return
    ($data, $doc2//ingr[@id = $ids])
```